# htaccess redirect remove query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this 301 redirect currently:

```
redirect 301 /oldurl http://www.domain.com/newurl
```

the problem is I get

```
http://www.domain.com/newurl?/oldurl
```

What syntax would i use with a `RewriteRule` instead for each url so I don't get the query string on the end?

Comment: how does your rewriterule look like exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Could do with some more details on the values for old and new url, but given the information provided:

```
RewriteRule ^oldurl$  newurl  [R=301,L]
```